# Spellings of あなた（がた）

Tags: spelling

The usual spelling would be hiragana for the first part and kanji for the second, but the spellings 貴女（方）(if the addressee is female) and 貴男（方）(if the addressee is male) are also in use. On to my question: the spelling 貴方 is more common than either, but then how would you write あなた方? My IME offers 貴方方, but that looks rather clunky. It doesn't offer 貴方々, but I can find examples of that spelling. Would the first or second spelling be more common? (As I've said, the *most* common is あなた方)

Comment: In a corpus of ~6000 novels (一般小説), I count `あなた方: 5698 occurrences`, `貴方方: 66 occurrences`,  and `貴方々:  4 occurrences`. Keep in mind 一般小説 are not a balanced corpus.

Comment: The [BCCWJ:Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) has got `あなた方: 705`, `貴方方: 3`, `貴方々: 0`.

Comment: [「会社-社長」「民主-主義」のように意味が区切れる場合は使用しないことが原則だが、「公演会々場」のように使われることもある。](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B8%8A%E3%82%8A%E5%AD%97#.E3.80.85.EF.BC.88.E5.90.8C.E3.81.AE.E5.AD.97.E7.82.B9.EF.BC.89)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend, but 「あなた方」 would usually be fine. I simplify a bit, but overusing kanji when not needed is not preferable in everyday text.
Not saying 「貴方方」would be taken bad in anyway, just have the master nit pickers frown.

This isn't something major or thought about normally, but in newspapers and such, they will usually use

「たぶん」over「多分」

「こちら」over「此方」

「または」over「又は」

As for 「貴方々」that is most likely a typo, since having 々 after a kanji means repeating that letter, there is a word「方々」, but in this case it's
「貴方」(you)[方](people）

Comment: The kanji repetition mark 々 can be used even if the repeated character doesn't use the same reading.  It's purely visual.  I don't believe 貴方々 Is a typo (even though I don't write it that way myself).

Comment: 「[貴方々は口の先許で、私大嫌ひです](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=7d3F4sHShjIC&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357&dq=%E8%B2%B4%E6%96%B9%E3%80%85&source=bl&ots=yKrhbJ4MeJ&sig=RSXyW0t7cjwPS4AEdLDrmzYYdzE&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBzgKahUKEwiptanfr4bHAhXGE5QKHTkiClA#v=onepage&q=%E8%B2%B4%E6%96%B9%E3%80%85&f=false)」 Note: pre-WWII orthography